# Electrum giving RPCerror during a send transaction. "the transaction was rejected by network rules. Missing inputs"

Tags: electrum, sending

In recent days due to the Electrum being attacked, I upgraded to the latest 3.3.2 Electrum. But now I'm getting the error as seen below:

> "the transaction was rejected by network rules. Missing inputs"

I tried picking many different servers and it's giving the same error. It says "missing inputs", but I picked an address with coins in it. So I'm not sure why it would be "missing".

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the hex txid in a comment or edit your question with the actual text?  I don't see a txid that starts with the hex copied from the image (though I might've made a mistake).  If the txid doesn't exist, the error is correct and valid since it means that the input really doesn't exist.